# Website is slow but cannot find culprit

Tags: performance, web, google-search-console

I have a ski holiday website http://www.powderwhite.com which Google Webmaster Tools say is slow (70% slower than other websites on the Internet).

Problem is that Google Developer Tools say we have done 90% of what is required to improve speed, speed tests also show the site is fairly fast and other websites hosted on the same virtual server are faster.

I think we have done lots to the site itself to make it fast and the hosting provider is saying it is not their servers. Anybody know what may be wrong? (I suspect jQuery or some javascript is slowing the site).

Answer (score 1):

Try using fiddler tool.  You can launch this then open the website in IE and in fiddler you can see each of the elements loaded on the page.  In the right window pane you can look at the statistics and inspectors to see if there is one image or file that is giving a slow response.

Comment: I highly recommend fiddler as well.  It could be something as simple as one very large image.